# Are decimal inch drills a thing?

Tags: tools

A cursory search indicates that drills size in round decimals of an inch (e.g. 0.3, 0.4, 0.15 inch) are not common, but are they a production item or would they only be available as some sort of custom or special purpose tooling?

What about for other "round hole" tools like mills and reamers? Looking up the second, they seem to be sized in terms of decimal inches, but the list I found didn't seem to have uniform increments so I suspect the choice of values came from something else.

Comment: Are uniform increments needed or are the tools designed around the dimensions used by designers and engineers? Sometimes the dimension is chosen as the next sensible dimension above the calculated value...

Comment: It is not common on daily encounters, but does exist in works require precision. See the drill bit size chart in the linked site - " https://www.engineersedge.com/drill_sizes.htm"

Comment: Yes they are, but the 3 standard size series in in inch are the "fractional", "letter" and "number" drills.

Comment: @SolarMike: Mostly I'm just curious, but I ran into a situation where the fractional, lettered and numbers left a gap around what I really wanted. I found a solution but it did get me wondering.

Comment: @r13: that chart lists only letter, number, fractional inch and decimal mm drills, which I guess supports your first claim that they are not common. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you have missed anything. I suggest to check the referenced ASTM standard to get to the bottom of it. I am quite curios on the meaning of those letters too :)

Comment: @r13 IIRC the numbered drills started out being derived from a wire size standard (e.g. approximately like wire gauge, and I think gauge is something akin to the number of time the wire has been drawn) and the letter just extend the same pattern to larger sizes. But I already knew that. :0)

Comment: @BCS I think you have me lost. I provide the linked chart only meant to show that, while the round decimal of an inch is uncommon, they do exist though.

Comment: @r13: that chart has only the drill series I mention above. While some of those sizes happen to be round decimal numbers, most round decimal numbers are not included. That is, it doesn't include a set of drill sizes that are chosen to provide decimal inch sizes, which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: @BCS I guess you are looking for metric equivalent sizes that are missing from the chart. I couldn't tell you why, but to remind you that the metric units and the US customary units are two not so compatible systems - one to one situation is hard to find in many areas. If the sizes are not on the chart, I guess they are not in use due to no/very low demand, at least in the USA.